# undefined method 'link' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have uploaded my project to heroku, but I get this error: `NoMethodError in Items#hype_item` and `undefined method "link" for nil:NilClass`. It works on my computer when I use localhost.

I have done done this:

1. heroku run rake db:create
2. herouk run rake db:migrate
3. heroku restart

...and read many posts on the issue, but it does not solve it.

Any suggestions?

Here is the log

```
2012-12-14T11:54:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ItemsController#hype_item as HTML
2012-12-14T11:54:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered items/hype_item.html.erb within layouts/application (75.2ms)
2012-12-14T11:54:03+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 405ms
2012-12-14T11:54:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-14T11:54:03+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `link' for nil:NilClass):
2012-12-14T11:54:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:        <p><div id="abc"><%= raw @item.link %></div></p>
2012-12-14T11:54:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     8: </div>
2012-12-14T11:54:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: 
2012-12-14T11:54:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/items/hype_item.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_items_hype_item_html_erb___686068816707788662_29579640'
2012-12-14T11:54:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-14T11:54:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: <div class="modal hide" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="tr">
2012-12-14T11:54:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:    <div class="modal-body">
2012-12-14T11:54:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:    </div>
2012-12-14T11:54:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-14T11:54:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (18.7ms)
2012-12-14T11:54:03+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=enigmatic-tor-2280.herokuapp.com fwd=84.48.62.139 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=16ms service=773ms status=500 bytes=26039
2012-12-14T11:54:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (29.9ms)
2012-12-14T11:54:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.0ms)
```

...and gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.6'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
gem "less-rails", "~> 2.2.6"
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', :require => 'bcrypt'


group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3' #mulig denne må flyttes ut av asset group for å virke
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

gem 'thin'
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

hype_item.html.erb

```
<div id="counter"></div>
<div id="play_button"> <a id="play" role="button"><%= image_tag("Play.png")%></a></div>

<div class="modal hide" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="tr">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p><div id="abc"><%= raw @item.link %></div></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Tell me if you need to see some more files, Im not sure whats relevant.

Comment: What's relevant is your app files that are in the stack trace.

Comment: What is stack trace? (Im relatively new to rails).

Comment: The error indicates that `@item` is nil at line 6 of `hype_item.html.erb:6`. Please check how it is initialized, and if you can't find why it is nil, post the code where it is initialized.

Comment: probably it was working in your localhost because you were using existing data in Item, you should seed or check if it exists

Comment: Does your app run on your local machine correctly in production mode?

Comment: Do you have data it can fetch in your production system?

Comment: Many good tips here. I tried this `<% if @item %> <%= raw @item.link %> <% end %>` in hype_item.html.erb, and then I got another error `couldn't find file "twitter/bootstrap"`. I have not tried to run it in production mode on my local machine, but will do.

Comment: Okey, so I am running it in production mode, and it behaves exactly like on heroku. I now have the `couldn't find file "twitter/bootstrap"` issue. Any sugestion to this?

Comment: you might have a problem with the asset pipeline. By default asset compression is disabled on development but enabled on production. Check the [guide on the asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) to see if you've done anything wrong. Maybe the bootstrap lib is not in asset precompilation path...

Comment: The code in `ItemsController#hype_item` would be helpful.  Consider deleting the Gemfile and view code above to trim down the post and stick the controller code in there (just the `hype_item` method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Baldrick pointed out the problem was that @item was nil.

So I changed from (in this in hype_item.html.erb):

```
<p><div id="abc"><%= raw @item.link %></div></p>
```

to:

```
<p><div id="abc"><% if @item %> <%= raw @item.link %> <% end %></div></p>
```

This might not be the best solution, but it worked.

Feel free to give a better solution, maybe this could be done in the controller.

Thanks for all the feedback!

Comment: `<%= raw @item.link if @item %>` should be enough.